# input with separated options (php, js, html)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

**Greetings all!**

I would like to ask you all for advice with my idea here. And your opinion. 
The thing is. I have **5 text inputs** and many **separated divs (options)**. When I click on div, I want to get it's value into one text inputs which I will choose by click before clicking on div (option).
For now, I have this:

```
<input type="text" class="mark" value="" id="choice1"/>

<input type="text" class="mark" value="" id="choice2"/>

<div class="copy">option1</div>
<div class="copy">option2</div>
<div class="copy">option3</div>
<div class="copy">option4</div>
<div class="copy">option5</div>
<div class="copy">option6</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '.mark', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var pokus = $(this).attr("class","paste")
       $(document).on('click', '.copy', function(a){
           a.preventDefault();
           $('.paste').val($(this).text());
        })
     });

</script>
```

So, when I click on input (with class "mark") it will also get class "paste", then I click on on of option (with class "copy") and it will be pasted into selected input.

Problem is, that I need to remove class "paste" after value from option is copied into input value. And here I got stucked.

When I try something like this:

```
$(document).getElementsByClassName("paste").removeClass('paste');
```

I get error that getElementsByClassName is not a function.

I want to ask you if someone has and idea how to make this happen. 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` return array, you must loop it and then for each element do `.removeClass`

Comment: You're mixing jQuery and DOM methods, just do `$('.paste').removeClass('paste');`.

Comment: Why is this question tagged as php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove class paste of all mark to have just one "selected", see preview ["Select" input with jquery](https://plnkr.co/edit/jlsR4eWd40OgB0ST?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

```
$(document).on('click', '.mark', function(e) {
    // Prevent multiple input select
    $(".mark").removeClass("paste")

    // Add class to "selected" input
    $(this).addClass("paste")
});

$(document).on('click', '.copy', function(a) {
    $('.paste').val($(this).text());
    $(".paste").removeClass("paste");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).on('click', '.mark', function(e){
      $('.mark').removeClass('paste');
       $(this).addClass("paste");
     });

 $(document).on('click', '.copy', function(a){
       $('.paste').val($(this).text());
 });
```